# Last array element in a row and first element in the next row having the same pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, visual-studio-2013, memory-address

I was working on a college assignment that required me to get a mathematical equation related to array pointers, I wrote the following code to display the pointers of all elements:

[image: Code to the left, output to the right.]

It was all smooth until I decided to convert the addresses to decimal to make my calculations easier, I used the following line of code:

```
size_t D = reinterpret_cast<size_t>(&X);
```

Once I did, somehow the last element in a row and first element in the next row returned the same address:

[image: Marked in red]

Even after I removed that line and restored my code to it's previous state, the specified elements still return the same address. I thought it might be a weird Visual Studio behavior and I tried restarting it, but the issue wasn't fixed. I'm wondering how this happened and how it can be fixed, it doesn't make sense.

Comment: Did you change the size of your array to `Arr[5][4]`?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Should have payed more attention, sorry. Yes I did, shouldn't that have returned an error or at least a warning though?

Would be appreciate it if you post an answer so I can accept it, sorry if I wasted your time over something this dumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of your array was changed to `Arr[5][4]`.  It won't return an error or warning as, they are all valid pointers to the 'one past the end' element of an array.

Comment: C and C++ don't implement array bounds checks, so there are no warnings or errors for this. Even if he goes further than "one past the end", it's undefined behavior.